# Unable to upload cookbook (because something is wrong with my recipe?)

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, recipe

I added another template to the existing recipe and the cookbook wont upload. This is my code:

`/cookbook/recipe/default.rb`

```
template "/opt/graphite/conf/blacklist.conf" do
  source "blacklist.erb"
  mode 0755
  variables( :mac => node[:graphite][:blacklist][:mac] )
end
```

`/cookbook/recipe/template/blacklist.erb`

```
mac = <%= @mac %>
```

`/cookbook/recipe/attributes/default.rb`

```
default[:graphite][:blacklist][:mac] = "xyz\.mac"
```

This was just to tell chef to create a blacklist file for graphite. What did I do wrong? This is my error:

```
Uploading graphite                       [1.0.5]
ERROR: Failed to upload #<Chef::CookbookVersion:0x00000001e2bcc8> : 500 Internal Server Error
{"error":["No such file or directory - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/chef-server-api-0.10.8.3/sandbox20121005-2129-1u45f5v.lock"]}
ERROR: Failed to upload #<Chef::CookbookVersion:0x00000001e2bcc8> : 500 Internal Server Error
{"error":["No such file or directory - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/chef-server-api-0.10.8.3/sandbox20121005-2129-1mlzi8g.lock"]}ERROR: RestClient::InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR: Failed to upload #<Chef::CookbookVersion:0x00000001e2bcc8> : 500 Internal Server Error
{"error":["No such file or directory - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/chef-server-api-0.10.8.3/sandbox20121005-2129-1pvrxcv.lock"]}
ERROR: Failed to upload #<Chef::CookbookVersion:0x00000001e2bcc8> : 500 Internal Server Error
{"error":["No such file or directory - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/chef-server-api-0.10.8.3/sandbox20121005-2129-1pl351l.lock"]}
ERROR: Failed to upload #<Chef::CookbookVersion:0x00000001e2bcc8> : 500 Internal Server Error
{"error":["No such file or directory - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/chef-server-api-0.10.8.3/sandbox20121005-2129-1crdpij.lock"]}
ERROR: Failed to upload #<Chef::CookbookVersion:0x00000001e2bcc8> : 500 Internal Server Error
{"error":["No such file or directory - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/chef-server-api-0.10.8.3/sandbox20121005-2129-v8ijj3.lock"]}
ERROR: Failed to upload #<Chef::CookbookVersion:0x00000001e2bcc8> : 500 Internal Server Error
{"error":["No such file or directory - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/chef-server-api-0.10.8.3/sandbox20121005-2129-ufrny2.lock"]}
ERROR: Failed to upload #<Chef::CookbookVersion:0x00000001e2bcc8> : 500 Internal Server Error
{"error":["No such file or directory - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/chef-server-api-0.10.8.3/sandbox20121005-2129-jtztmr.lock"]}

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:48:in `return!': 500 Internal Server Error (RestClient::InternalServerError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:230:in `process_result'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:178:in `block in transmit'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:172:in `transmit'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:64:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:33:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/resource.rb:76:in `put'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/chef-0.10.8.3/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:134:in `block in uploader_function_for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/chef-0.10.8.3/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:25:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/chef-0.10.8.3/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in setup_worker_threads'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/chef-0.10.8.3/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:24:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/chef-0.10.8.3/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in setup_worker_threads'
```

Comment: There is something wrong with your chef-server. Could you show chef-server logs?

Comment: @DracoAter: Thanks, that actually narrowed my problem and was able to solve it :)

Comment: Write an answer, how you solved it and accept it. :)

Comment: I personally hate when this happens. This might be a problem which other people are facing and yet, you solved and didn't post the answer. Shame on you!

Comment: @vanemaster I am sorry but I actually didn't figure it out till the end. The above comment was premature as it worked partially and returned another error which I thought I knew the answer too but turns out my approach was wrong.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? @vanemaster while I agree, there's (literally) 1000 reasons the Chef Server isn't responding. So while it'd be nice to have an answer, there's a very low probability it would help others.

Comment: @sethvargo This was a long time back so I need to jog my memory, but I think it was because of some couchDB issue. I can't seem to remember if I actually re-installed from scratch or just restarted couchDB. But the root cause, I still don't know =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was totally un-related to the cookbooks. There was some issue with couchDB and since this was a long time back I can't seem to remember if I had to re-install or just restart couchDB but it did fix the issue.